# Show error message on SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I'm using a SearchView in the ActionBar and I'd like to know if it's possible to show an error if the input is invalid, similar as `EditText`'s `showError()` method.

I know that this could be anti pattern because *any search shouldn't be invalid*. I configured the `SearchView` to react in a way that if it detects that the user put something and that something is similar to anything valid then it will advert it to the user. But for that purpose I'd like to get the same effect as `EditText`'s `showError()` method, as I said before.

Is this possible or I'll have to conform with showing a `Toast` or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
int id = searchView.getContext()
                        .getResources()
                        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(id);
editText.setError("Your error message");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this!

Comment: if you are using appcompat SearchView use `SearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)` which returns `SearchView.SearchAutoComplete` which is an EditText so you can call `setError` on the `SearchView.SearchAutoComplete->setError("there was an error")` Although on my phone the error does not show fully