# How can I use setError() on a SearchView?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I know how to set error on `EditText` like this:

```
 serverIp.setError("Server IP Is Required");
        serverIp.requestFocus();
        return;
```

But in `SearchView` there is no option to set Error.

Is there any way to get the result?

Comment: Have u try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440644/show-error-message-on-searchview

Comment: Yes @NileshRathod and its not working

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not working"?

Comment: Nilesh's link should work, try again

Answer (score 0):

> But in `SearchView` there is no option to set Error.

Indeed. There is [no public method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView#public-methods) (*I couldn't find any at least*) related to `setError()` in `SearchView` since it extends from `LinearLayoutCompat` and not the `EditText` to use `setError()`.

Instead, you can use an `EditText` inside a `CardView` to handle the `setError()`.

---

Also, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47573025/4409113

```
private fun setErrorOnSearchView(searchView: SearchView, errorMessage: String) {
    val id = searchView.context
            .resources
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)
    val editText = searchView.find<EditText>(id)
    editText.error = errorMessage
}
```

You might be able to declare-bypass the `SearchView` as an `EditText` to use `setError()`.